# Вывод произвольных постов по таксономии

Tags: wordpress, cms

Здравствуйте. я знаю , что я должен использовать класс WP_Query и цикл, но я не могу получить пользовательскую запись из базы данных по таксономии, например , "categorydocuments" . Я читал , что я должен был использовать шаблон ' taxonomy-{slug}' , но я уже не знаю , как правильно писать там цикл и какие аргументы передать в WP_Query.

Например, я , перейдя по ссылке ' и я получаю сообщение с post_type 'documents' и таксономией 'categorydocuments'.

как я могу получить таксономию «private» и поставить эту таксономию в $args для WP_Query? Пожалуйста, не предлагайте мне варианты парсинга ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

В аргументы к WP_Query нужно добавить массив tax_query. Вот здесь документация: http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#parametry-taksonomij

Comment: это я понимаю. но как мне из УРЛ-а, скажем так, получить название категории.

Comment: Если вы хотите составить урлы для таксономии, курите add_rewrite_rule . Там добавляются правила для постоянных ссылок типа site.com/mytaxonomy/myterm/post . Эти параметры записываются в query_vars , потом в шаблоне их можно достать и подставить в цикл. А если же вам надо просто получить ссылку на архив, используйте get_post_type_archive_link() и get_term_link(). Я просто не совсем понял, чего вы хотите добиться)

Comment: Стоп. Если вы используете встроенные шаблоны WP, типа category, archive, taxonomy, tag и прочее, то вам нет необходимости писать кастомный цикл. Вставляете в шаблон базовый луп, без аргументов, WP все подставит без вас.

Comment: Спасибо, видимо неправильно истолковал прочитанное. аргументы для taxonomy-{slug} передавать не надо было. Есть немного другой вопрос. Если я ставлю один из параметров ('rewrite' => array('hierarchical' => true)) для функции register_taxonomy(), то я не могу достучаться до дочерних категорий. Как быть в таком случае, так как не представляю, в какую сторону копать. В свою же очередь, если я свалю 'rewrite' => true, то все работает нормально. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Вот с этим не помогу. Я типы постов и таксономии создаю плагином CPT UI, поэтому не знаком с функциями регистрации.